# How does Baby Groot know Drax is looking at him when he dances?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, groot

Baby Groot stops dancing whenever Drax looks at him, we see this almost instantly at the end of *Guardians of the Galaxy* and also in the opening scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*. Why he stops dancing is pretty obvious, Drax disapproves of such things and so he doesn't want to get hurt by him. Gunn has also said pretty much the same thing in an interview:

> “There was actually a scene that we cut from the movie where big Groot was dancing to 'Livin’ Thing' by ELO,” said Gunn. “And it wasn’t such an elaborate dance. It was more that he was just moving up and down like this, and Drax was dismissive and gave him this look like he was a loser when he did that.”
>
> Gunn added, “Dancing is ludicrous to Drax. I don’t think he understands it. If Drax owned a town, if he was a mayor, the first law would be no dancing. But yeah, so at the end of the movie, little baby Groot didn’t want to get caught dancing, because he would kill him.”
>
> <sub>[comicbook, Guardians Of The Galaxy Cut Scene Reveals Why Baby Groot Hid His Dancing From Drax](https://comicbook.com/news/guardians-of-the-galaxy-cut-scene-reveals-why-baby-groot-hid-his/)</sub>

So, we know *why* he stops dancing but do we know how he even knows Drax is looking at him in the first place so he can stop? In the GotG2 opening scene he might have heard it was Drax behind him, however, he doesn't stop dancing straight away only when Drax looks. And when you watch it at 0.25 speed Groot isn't even looking towards Drax.

**How does he know Drax is looking at him when he can't see behind himself?**

Comment: Sixth sense (noun): 
a supposed intuitive faculty giving awareness not explicable in terms of normal perception.

Comment: Out of universe answer "He sees his own reflection (and Drax) in the lens of the camera filming him". In universe answer "He sees his own reflection (and Drax) in display screen he's facing"

Comment: "Who knows what evil lurks in the hearts of men? The Shadow knows!"

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I know this is pretty much tongue in cheek but I did check anyway and unless I missed it he's not near the speakers or anything else at that moment. He's also looking towards the Abilisk at that moment.

Comment: As we know from Infinity War, Drax has almost certainly become entirely invisible at the time too, so Sapling Groot won't "see" him in the way that we understand.

Comment: Are Groot's "eyes" (a) actually what he sees with and (b) the only visual organs he has?

Comment: @DavidW As far as I'm aware yes but maybe I don't know enough here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Yes, tongue was firmly embedded in cheek while I typed :p

Comment: A similar question can be asked of Drax - How does Drax know to look at Groot when he's dancing?

Answer (score 1):

The [script](https://storyfactory.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/15.-Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-2.pdf) indicates that Groot most likely *heard/felt* Drax land behind him. There is, as you've rightly pointed out, no goodly reason for the pause (e.g. until Drax is looking directly at him), but that's possibly because Groot has other senses than mere sight/hearing/feeling. In the comics he's mildly telepathic, for example.

> As Groot DANCES, Drax FALLS directly behind him.
> Groot FREEZES.
> Drax stares at him a moment, suspicious. Groot stays frozen.
> Drax LEAVES, and Groot COMMENCES THE DANCE where he left off.

---

Obviously out-of-universe the answer is "*because it's [funnier that way](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)*", even if it [makes little sense](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim).

Comment: This is only one incident of course and doesn’t explain some of the other times we see this such as at the end of GotG. Even for this incident it’s questionable.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I'm sticking with 'other senses'